# File upload using jquery and html

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have written html as

```
 <form class="uploadfile">
 <input type="file" size="40"/>
 <br/>
 <button onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

in jquery

```
function upload()
{

}
```

I have created uploads folder where all the uploaded files will be saved...
Basically I want that whenever the file is uploaded in the Uploads folder, it should show  the link. When that link is clicked the file should get displayed.
Can anyone help me!!!

Answer (score 3):

You want to use something like [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects).

```
var formData = new FormData();    
formData.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
    url: 'uploadScript.php',
    data: formData ,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
    {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

You store the file in the FormData object and upload it, how you handle it is quite straightforward depending on your server-side language and should not be very complicated for you to continue with :)

Once you've uploaded the file and saved it properly you can query the storage and generate the links.

**Edit**

What you're asking for is impossible; a normal HTTP file to be uploaded by JavaScript only. You need a server side programming language to handle the upload and store the file on the server's file system. The client's only purpose is to provide the file to the server.

Comment: Sorry I don't need any php scripts... Actually I have to use only jquery and html

Comment: @Nida Files that are stored on the server must be stored by the server meaning you have to use a server-side programming language to do the job. The client's only purpose is to take the file, store it into an object and send that object to the server.